# Parse a text file in PHP, where the format of data changes

Tags: php, parsing, text-files

My data looks like this.

```
123456  abc1 (aaa: [bbb]aaa)    http://exampleurl.org.uk

654321 cba2 (bbb: aa7)  http://urlexample.org.uk
...
```

I would like to split each row into 3 strings, so I can put them into an array. 
E.g:

```
string 1 = 123456   

string 2 = abc1 (aaa: [bbb]aaa)

string 3 = http://exampleurl.org.uk
```

My problem is that the second string is often changing with lots of different formats. The first string is always similar, and the last string is always a url.

EDIT: I have noticed that all of the 2nd strings end with a bracket ')' if this helps.

I was going to use explode() but I'm not sure how to deal with the second string. Any advice?

Comment: If there is always a closing bracket at the end of the second string, you could use a regular expression. Or you could use one that extracts any number at the beginning and anything after the string `https?://`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I would probably just use a regex, this is also an option:

```
function parse($str)
{
    $parts = explode(" ", $str);

    // first part of the exploded str
    $number = array_shift($parts);

    // last part of the exploded str
    $url = array_pop($parts);

    // all thats left is the middle str
    $between = trim(implode(" ", $parts), " ");

    return array($number, $between, $url);
}

$str = "123456  abc1 (aaa: [bbb]aaa)    http://exampleurl.org.uk";

print_r(parse($str));
```

Output:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '123456' (length=6)
  1 => string 'abc1 (aaa: [bbb]aaa)' (length=20)
  2 => string 'http://exampleurl.org.uk' (length=24)
```

Comment: you could `$number=$parts[0];unset($parts[0]);` instead of `array_shift()` since you don't care about the keys here and would be faster on a large file.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression:

```
$input = "123456  abc1 (aaa: [bbb]aaa)    http://exampleurl.org.uk";
preg_match("/([0-9]+)\s+(.+)\s+(http:\/\/.*)/i", $input, $matches);
```

This will store the result into `$matches`L

```
Array
(
  [0] => 123456  abc1 (aaa: [bbb]aaa)    http://exampleurl.org.uk
  [1] => 123456
  [2] => abc1 (aaa: [bbb]aaa)   
  [3] => http://exampleurl.org.uk
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your format is actually quite simple:

```
Number - Space(s) - Random Stuff - Space(s) - URL
```

So all you need is a regex like this:

```
^(\d+)\s+(.*?)\s+(URL)$
```

Where `URL` is your preference in URL-matching regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The first string can also contain letters and symbols sometimes, but doesn't ever have spaces. So would that make it easier as I'd just look for the first space?

Answer (score 0):

If there are always spaces or always tabs between `$string1`, `$string2` and `$string3` you can do something like that:

```
$line = '123456  abc1 (aaa: [bbb]aaa)    http://exampleurl.org.uk';
$string1 = substr($line, 0, ($pos = strpos($line, ' '))); // use "\t" instead of ' ' if tab is delimiter
$string2 = trim(substr($line, $pos, ($pos2 = strrpos($line, ' ')) - $pos));
$string3 = substr($line, $pos2 + 1);
```

that will be much faster than regex or exploding and joining arrays